# unit test runs properly but at the end it returns npm error

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to test a component using @vue-jest in Nuxt. It runs suit and reports me if a test is passed or not but at the end of the report using "npm run test" I have the error:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved, it was because Snapshot Summary and I removed it by "npm test -- -u" command.